# How to cancel a long-running Amazon Glacier file upload operation in .NET C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, amazon-glacier

I am new to Amazon AWS and Glacier.
I am trying to write a WPF Windows-based C# client that uploads my archived backup data to the glacier cloud.
However, the API reference don't seem to offer a cancel command. Only upload, download, list.

What I'm trying to do is run each upload operation (which can take 1 hour or more with large files) asynchronously using TPL. 
However I want the upload to be cancellable, which .NET 4.5 would support nicely, but the Amazon API does not.

Is there a way to do that anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to handle your scenario in [Amazon Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/) (and [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) as well btw.) is to *Upload archives in parts* via *Multipart Upload*, see [Uploading an Archive in Amazon Glacier](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-an-archive.html):

> Depending on the size of the data you are uploading, Amazon Glacier
>   offers the following options:
>
> - **Uploading Large Archives in Parts (Multipart Upload)** — In a single operation, you can upload archives from 1 byte to up to 4 GB in size. **However, we
>     encourage Amazon Glacier customers to use Multipart Upload to upload
>     archives greater than 100 MB.** [...] *[emphasis mine]*
> - **Upload archives in parts** — Using the Multipart upload API you can upload large archives, up to about 40,000 GB (10,000 * 4 GB).

[Uploading Large Archives in Parts (Multipart Upload)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-archive-mpu.html) provides the details on the latter, specifically regarding **Complete (or Abort) Multipart Upload**:

> After uploading all the archive parts, you use the complete operation.
>   [...]
>
> If you abort a multipart upload, you cannot upload any more parts
>   using that multipart upload ID. All storage consumed by any parts
>   associated with the aborted multipart upload is freed. **If any part
>   uploads were in-progress, they can still succeed or fail even after
>   you abort.** *[emphasis mine]*

So you still can't abort the uploads of parts that are in progress as such, thus the key for the desired user experience and/or network bandwidth reduction is choosing a small enough part size.

Depending on your use case you might also want to check into [List Multipart Uploads (GET multipart-uploads)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-multipart-list-uploads.html):

> This multipart upload operation lists in-progress multipart uploads
>   for the specified vault. An in-progress multipart upload is a
>   multipart upload that has been initiated by an [Initiate Multipart
>   Upload (POST multipart-uploads)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-multipart-initiate-upload.html) request, but has not yet been
>   completed or aborted. [...]